How to make a function that takes 2 dimensional array of Extended and return TArray<Extended>?
I have this function to solve 3x4 matrix by Gaussian elimination. But i got this error when running the program.

[Error] Unit1.pas(79): Identifier expected but 'ARRAY' found


[Error] Unit1.pas(79): Undeclared identifier: 'TArray'

function Solve3x4MatrixByGaussianElimination(A: array of array of Extended): TArray<Extended>;
const
  Rows = 3;
  Cols = 4;
var
  i, j, k: Integer;
  factor: Extended;
  X: array of Extended;
begin
  SetLength(X, Rows);

  for i := 0 to Rows - 2 do
  begin
    for k := i + 1 to Rows - 1 do
    begin
      if Abs(A[i, i]) < Abs(A[k, i]) then
      begin
        for j := 0 to Cols - 1 do
        begin
          factor := A[i, j];
          A[i, j] := A[k, j];
          A[k, j] := factor;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    for k := i + 1 to Rows - 1 do
    begin
      factor := A[k, i] / A[i, i];
      for j := i to Cols - 1 do
        A[k, j] := A[k, j] - factor * A[i, j];
    end;
  end;

  X[Rows - 1] := A[Rows - 1, Cols - 1] / A[Rows - 1, Rows - 1];
  for i := Rows - 2 downto 0 do
  begin
    X[i] := A[i, Cols - 1];
    for j := i + 1 to Rows - 1 do
      X[i] := X[i] - A[i, j] * X[j];
    X[i] := X[i] / A[i, i];
  end;

  Result := X;
end;

I wonder how to solve this, I've been looking to some solution such as the Uses I need to use, but still failed. I am working on Delphi 7.

You don't get the error when you "run" the program, but when you try to compile it. Anyhow: Generics like TArray<Extended> were added in Delphi 2009, several years after Delphi 7 was released. So you need to use array of Extended instead. To use such a type as a function return value type, you need to declare type TExtendedArray = array of Extended or similar, as detailed in numerous SO Q&As.

Generics were introduced in Delphi 2009, they simply didn't exist yet in Delphi 7, which is why you are getting an error on TArray<Extended>.
If you really want to return a Dynamic Array, you need an explicit type for it, eg:
type
  TArrayOfExtended = array of Extended;

function Solve3x4MatrixByGaussianElimination(A: ...): TArrayOfExtended;
...
var
  ...
  X: TArrayOfExtended;
begin
  ...
  Result := X;
end;

That being said, when you use array of ... directly in a parameter type, it declares the parameter as an Open Array, not a Dynamic Array.  You can't use array of array of ... as a parameter type because an Open Array of Open Array makes no sense.
In this situation, to pass in a 2D array, you can use either:

a static array:
type
  TMatrix = array[0..2] of array[0..3] of Extended;
  TArrayOfExtended = array of Extended;

function Solve3x4MatrixByGaussianElimination(var A: TMatrix): TArrayOfExtended;


a Dynamic Array of Dynamic Array:
type
  TArrayOfExtended = array of Extended;
  T2DArrayOfExtended = array of TArrayOfExtended;

function Solve3x4MatrixByGaussianElimination(A: T2DArrayOfExtended): TArrayOfExtended;




Why make the parameter a var parameter rather than const?

Becauer the function is modifying the content of the array

Ouch, sorry, I missed that.
